# Query to clear sql server logs over a certain age

Tags: sql-server-2008, logging, sql-server-2012

I would like to write a query to clear any SQL Server logs older than 4 days. This is the folder of the SSMS I'm referring to:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What have you tried already? Have a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and check whether you think your question fits the format for StackExchange.

Comment: Well... I wouldn't do it by date since the "Current" error log could span multiple days so why not just recycle aka limit the number of error logs stored and / or limit the max size of the individual error log?